# AWS lambda NodeJS: Route traffic through squid proxy

Tags: node.js, lambda, proxy

I am very new to NodeJS. I am trying to pass traffic through a squid proxy from a NodeJS lambda. Here's my code.

```
var http = require('http'),
    tls = require('tls');

var req = http.request({
    host: 'proxy.us-east-1.nonprod.aws.prv',
    port: 3128,
    method: 'CONNECT',
    path: 'aws.amazon.com:443'
});

exports.handler = async function (event) { 
  req.on('connect', function (res, socket, head) {
    var tlsConnection = tls.connect({
        host: 'aws.amazon.com',
        socket: socket
    }, function () {
        tlsConnection.write('GET / HTTPS/1.1\r\nHost: aws.amazon.com\r\n\r\n');
    });

    tlsConnection.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
    });
});

req.end();
};
```

When I run it, it says "null" in the response. Any suggestions would be appreciated.